# Null pointer Exception while injecting data source in Mockito

Tags: spring, nullpointerexception, mockito

I am trying to inject a datasource and probably successful. But the jdbctemplate is having issues getting the connection.

```
@Mock
BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

@org.junit.Before
public void setUP(){
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@myurl");
    dataSource.setUsername("myid");
    dataSource.setPassword("mypassword");
    dataSource.setInitialSize(5);
    dataSource.setMaxActive(10);
    dataSource.setPoolPreparedStatements(true);
    dataSource.setMaxOpenPreparedStatements(10);
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testGetMyMethod(){
    MyDAOImpl impl = new MyDAOImpl(dataSource);     
    try {
        long number  = impl.getMyMethod();
        System.out.println(number);
    } catch (MasterIdApplicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:399)
```

My DAO Impl is like

```
    @Autowired
public MyDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
    super();
    setDataSource(dataSource);      
}

public long getMyMethod() throws MasterIdApplicationException {
    Long number = this.getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(MY_SQL, Long.class);
    return number;
}
```

Can you please check what is the issue?

Comment: Why is `dataSource` annotated with `@Mock`? Looks real to me.

Comment: Like @Stewart said, either instantiate it yourself, or define it as a mock. Also  you should probably call MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); before trying to use any mock instance...